# cannot call webmethod with parameters

Tags: c#, webmethod

I have a web method in C#, when it have no parameter, I call reach a breakpoint in the web method.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetIDForDownloadExcel()
    {
        ChartEdit cd = new ChartEdit();
        Guid clientID = Guid.NewGuid();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ClientID = clientID, filename = "ExportToExcel" });
    }
```

I call it using the following code.

```
         function GetReportID() {                
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("ChartEdit.aspx/GetIDForDownloadExcel") %>',
                data: JSON.stringify({ ind: indicatorsIds, loc: locationsIds }),
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Data: ' + data.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

You can see, the webmethod is having no parameter. Breakpoint can be reached in the method. Then I want the webmethod to receive the json data passed in Ajax ( data: JSON.stringify({ ind: indicatorsIds, loc: locationsIds }), I changed the WebMethod as follows which have parameters.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetIDForDownloadExcel(string ind,string loc)
    {
        ChartEdit cd = new ChartEdit();
        Guid clientID = Guid.NewGuid();

        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { ClientID = clientID, filename = "ExportToExcel" });
    }
```

However, the webmethod cannot be reached again, it cannot reach the breakpoint in the method. How can I called the webmethod that can receive the data passed in json?

Comment: What happens if you remove `JSON.stringify(`?

Comment: Also - `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: var data = { "ind": indicatorsIds, "loc": locationsIds }; in ajax using data: JSON.stringify(data), it may help you. And can you write what json in request send to server?

Comment: Is that means it is no problem to add parameters in HetIDForDownloadExcel, and I can call it successfully?

Comment: I don't any issues with the code. The only way I reproduced is by sending undefined like data: JSON.stringify({ ind: undefined , loc: undefined }). Are you sure indicatorsIds and locationsIds have values?

Comment: @mahesh_b The indicatorsIds can be "1234","4567" and locationsIds can be "4","5"

Comment: I get that point..did you debug whether these variables have values during ajax call?

Comment: @mahesh_b check the values, they are having values.

Answer (score 0):

I print the error response text in ajax. And it is as follows:

```
type 'system.string' is not supported for deserialization of an array
```

So I found out it is the problem of the parameter of signature of webmethod in C#, because 
ajax passed in array variable. But the parameter in c# is

```
(string ind,string loc)
```

which I changed to array variables (stirng[] ind, string[] loc), then the webmethod can be called.